# iOS, Core Data. Request all records from table which begin with number symbol without additional data processing?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, numeric, nsfetchrequest

There a lot of solutions here with using of "MATCHES", which simply doesn't work in this case:

```
2013-08-20 10:30:40.890 ColonialChadstone[2609:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unimplemented SQL generation for predicate (SELF MATCHES "[0-9]+.*")'
```

The final solution should look like:

```
NSFetchedRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *predicateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '%@'", @"[0-9]+.*"];
[request setPredicate:predicateStr];
NSArray *resultArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Comment: You should show *your* actual code first instead of only requesting a solution.

Comment: ok here you are. But the question is so clear that this code doesn't affect it

Comment: How does this compile? `setPredicate:` takes an NSPredicate argument, not NSString.

Comment: Additionally I want to say that I have found a solution by myself but your one is much better. I tried to use NSCompoundPredicate which contains a lot of `NSPredicates` which look like "%@ BEGINSWITH %@"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Valentin is right that you should avoid using string formatting functions when creating
predicates. It might work in your case, but is error-prone in general, because the format
specifiers and quoting rules differ between `stringWithFormat` and `predicateWithFormat`.)

The problem with your predicate is that you cannot compare the managed object itself ("SELF")
against a pattern, only a *specific attribute* of the managed object:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attribute MATCHES %@", @"[0-9]+.*"]
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Nice. I think I have tried all the possible combinations of arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateStr]];` instead of putting `NSString`